# JButtons perform the same task

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, actionevent

I'm trying to make a program with two J Buttons that will do different tasks. but when I run the program both buttons do the same thing. I guess its because it is because the "this" keyword . can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class NextPage extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    NextPage()
    {
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();

        JButton docbutton = new JButton();   //second button
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

        tabbedPane1.add("booking",panel1);
        tabbedPane1.add("Doctors Screen",panel2);
        tabbedPane1.add("Register",panel3);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(tabbedPane1);
        frame.setSize(600, 500);
        frame.setTitle("Welcome to DoctorsCare");

        frame.setVisible(true);

        JButton button = new JButton();         //first button  
        button.setLabel("Take Appointment");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160,40));
        panel1.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(this);
        docbutton.setLabel("patient-1");
        panel2.add(docbutton);
        docbutton.addActionListener(this); 
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
            BookingPage page = new BookingPage();   
        }

    public void ap(ActionEvent ae)
    {
            DoctorsScreen dscrn = new DoctorsScreen();
        }
        }
```

Comment: The `actionPerformed` method gets called when an action is performed, and you can use `ae.getActionCommand()` to see which button caused the event. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html

Comment: You should use `Action` instead. It's far superior to using `ActionListener`.

Comment: @Kayaman docbutton.setAction((Action) this);  you mean like this?

Comment: No, I mean you should read the documentation on how to use `Action`, then be amazed at how convenient it is. If you're going to keep guessing "like this?" instead of doing a bit of googling and reading, you're not going to get anything done.

Comment: Since I'm such a nice guy, I got you the tutorial on using `Actions`. Read the others too. Consider it an early xmas present: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html